# Change log level at runtime for a cf application based on SAP Java Buildpack

Tags: sap-cloud-platform, sap-cloud-sdk, sap-cloud-foundry

Following the guide over here:
https://sap.github.io/cloud-sdk/docs/java/guides/logging-overview#logging-overview

I am trying to use CF CLI `cf set-env` command to change the logs levels at runtime.
This commands executes successfully and the log levels are only changed when I do a `cf restage srv` or `cf restart srv`. `srv` is the name of my application.

Is there any alternative where I don't have to stop the cf application and still be able to change the log levels at runtime?

Comment: Is there a specific reason why you would want to change log levels so frequently that a restart of the application is cumbersome? Also, which logging framework are you using? In case you [started with an SDK Archetype](https://sap.github.io/cloud-sdk/docs/java/getting-started) that would be Logback by default.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No, I think in order to reload the setting from environment variables a reload is required.

You could instead implement a new endpoint in your application where you set the log level programatically. But that depends on the logging framework you are using. E.g. for Logback this can be done as [described here](http://logback.qos.ch/manual/configuration.html#joranDirectly).